# Scaling of microservice to handle more request

Tags: microservices, couchbase, scaling

I am using couchbase as a DB for my Sprint boot microservice. To handle more request/sec I want to create more instances of my service. How can we handle this design to make the DB consistent? As of now, I have a single couchbase running and 4 instances of my service.

I am thinking of future problem by running more instances.As all request are creating data (posting) data to CB.

Answer (score 0):

If your single server is maxed out, you need to add more servers. The docs explain how to do that.

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/manage/manage-nodes/add-node-and-rebalance.html

If your consistency concerns are fairly simple, CAS values may solve your problem.

https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/document-operations.html

If you have more detailed concerns about consistency, you need to explain what they are in your question. Generally speaking, if consistency is a priority, a NoSQL database like Couchbase is probably not the right tool for you.

Comment: While it's true Couchbase is not a silver bullet, it's worth noting that reads and writes via the Couchbase key/value API are indeed strongly consistent (in the sense that everyone else can immediately read your writes). It's even possible to do consistent reads via the Query service using scan consistency options (although that's a bit more expensive than the normal eventually-consistent queries).